# How to remove below view programmatically?

Tags: android, android-windowmanager

I am adding below view for block status bar using below code.

```
WindowManager manager = ((WindowManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE));
WindowManager.LayoutParams localLayoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
localLayoutParams.type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR;
localLayoutParams.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
localLayoutParams.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE |
    // this is to enable the notification to recieve touch events
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL |
    // Draws over status bar
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN;

localLayoutParams.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
int heightSize = 50;

localLayoutParams.height = (int) (heightSize * mContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().scaledDensity);
localLayoutParams.format = PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT;
mCustomViewGroup = new customViewGroup(mContext);
manager.addView(mCustomViewGroup, localLayoutParams);
```

When Application launch, above code will execute.

In My Application, if user is in Settings screen, 
Then I want to reset status bar(Remove Status bar).

I tried below ways but did not get success.

1. manager.removView(mCustomViewGroup);
2. set height = 0 and 
   manager.updateViewLayout(mCustomViewGroup, localLayoutParams);

**How to remove or Update View for the particular activity?**

I have to do this because If status bar is blocked and app asking for permission, Then Screen Overlay Detected and not able to grant or deny permission.

Comment: Have you tried manager.removAllViews():

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
    public void run() {
       manager.removeView(mCustomViewGroup);
    }
});
```

Comment: Ok Trying and will be back.

Comment: Above code is for add view first time. From other activity how to remove that view? or How to find this added view from the other activity?

Answer (score 0):

Will hide the view make sense ?

`mCustomViewGroup.setVisibility(View.GONE);`

Comment: Above code is for add view first time. From other activity how to remove that view? or How to find this added view from the other activity?

Comment: You can not add/remove a view from another activity. A View is always attached to a single activity.